# How to dynamically add form elements to an existing form?

Tags: javascript

So, I basically need to do what the title says, dynamically add form elements with a button to a form.

I currently have a form that is loaded by a button. This form is within a jQuery popup box. I currently have a button underneath this form which should add a few elements each time to the form. This button does not currently work, and I am really not to sure on how to do this.

This is what I need added every time, in this format:

```
Question [text-box]       Dummy 1 [text-box]
                          Dummy 2 [text-box]
                          Dummy 3 [text-box]
                          Correct [text-box]
                          [delete-button]
```

Basically, a new question will be added, along with another 4 text boxes next to it for incorrect answers, and one correct answer. There must also be a delete button underneath them to delete that question completely. I'll be adding all the functionality later on, although I need the dynamic adding and deleting working.

This is what i currently have:

```
function addNewQuizField()
{
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 10;
    var quizForm = document.getElementById('newQuizForm');

    if (counter == limit)  
    {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " questions");
     }
     else 
     {
          var newQuest = document.createElement('div');
          newQuest.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(quizForm).appendChild(newQuest);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

This is my function that creates the quiz form (messy, I know):

```
function createQuizForm()
{
    var quizForm = '<form name="editForm" id="newQuizForm" method="post" action="createplay.php"><input type=hidden id="dialogid" name="dialogid" value=""><input type=hidden id="dialogtype" name="dialogtype" value=""><input type=hidden id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>"><div>Quiz Name: <input type="text" id="nameEdit" name="nameEdit" value=""></div><div>Embed Code: <textarea id="textEdit" name="textEdit" row="10" cols="50"></textarea></div><input type="submit" class="roundButton upload" value="" /><input name="addNewField" type="button" onClick="addNewQuizField();" /></form>';

    var dialogDiv = document.getElementById('dialog');

    dialogDiv.innerHTML = quizForm;

    OpenNewQuizDialog();
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a jQuery popup box but choose to make the rest work in plain JavaScript? Why not use jQuery for that too?

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. It was a jQuery pre made GUI thing that I grabbed and integrated. I am more than happy to add jQuery for this part, although I cannot write it or edit it myself. I am familiar with plain Javascript, but I am no expert.

Comment: Can you share your code so far? Your html, your javascript. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @3dgoo - Added my javascript function that adds the form. Although, I do not currently have anything that does the dynamic adding since I failed epicly at it.

Comment: Why are you creating the form in javascript, rather than having it in html? Looking at your code I can see a problem. Your button to add a new field calls the function `addNewQuizField()`. But there is not function named `addNewQuizField()`. Your function is called `addInput()` and takes 1 parameter `divName`.

Comment: @3dgoo - Made an edit on the addNewQuizField function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for with your current code? Check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SC0rWLN9oXALtoI9LfQ?p=preview).

Comment: Can you add your code here with an explanation so that it is still useful to others in the future in case your link goes down?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu - I already had that working, exactly the same as your preview. You basically just used my exact code haha? My question is that I need to restructure my code to match the format that I posted.

Comment: @fizzix - In your comments you said you could not get this working. And Nicolae has got this working, as asked. Now you just need to change it slightly to add a few more fields. If you cannot do this, I think you should go and take the time to learn javascript and html so you have the basic skills to do this yourself. Rather than asking people to alter your code as you need.